# Couldnt link two xml pages in android development(SDK)

Tags: android

am trying to link two xml pages activity_main and activity_addbaby. i have a button in activity_main when i click on that i should be on the other xml file it switches to another xml but emulator doesnt show the UI elements in the xml

my code is like

Main activity
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View V)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Addbaby.class);
              startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

and Addbaby.class is like 
public class Addbaby extends Activity
{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addbaby);
```

}

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="New Profile" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Existing Profile" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my linked xml file is

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="92dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
  </EditText>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="Name" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="DOB" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:text="email" />

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/add_Baby_dob"
    android:layout_width="200.0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not the good way to see things, you switch from one to another activity and not from xml file to another.
However, it would works. You should post the layout files, the problem probably come from the xml code.

Comment: I am doing it in the way you said ok am enclosing my layout files as well here they are

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an improper definition of the **relative layout** in the second layout , and keep `android:context=.className` in the definition of the relative layout